# How to import a json file to MongoDB

Tags: mongoimport

I have some problem to import a json file to mongo.
Here is what i wrote:

```
mongoimport --db tst --collection stocks --type json --file //home/ubuntu/workspace/stocksNsdq.json --jsonArray
```

This is the error that i got:

```
2014-08-23T15:05:09.569+0000 SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

Comment: Could you post a sample structure from your json file ?

Comment: the problem is not with the file, because on Windows i was able to run the same command and the data was imported, i'm wondering if i need to install the mongoimport tool which was installed on Windows

Comment: Usually mongoimport is installed by default, but the error posted above looks like something is wrong with the json

Comment: Where can i find it on linux?

Comment: Just type this in your terminal `whereis mongoimport`

Comment: Thanks a lot it's working, I've tried this command when i was inside the mongoshell that's why it didn't recognize it